# Change APK (from AppInventor) asset (data) via C# without "recompile"

Tags: c#, apk, assets, app-inventor

I've been doing some Android Application in [MIT AppInventor](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu) and generated a Sample APK (it's all available in [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OGkqK8ufKRKNpZVxCsISTLo3E4UDYYRJ) for reference - the AIA, APK an CS files).

On my project (AIA) i placed a "**Data.txt**" file as an Asset with the text "oops". What i'd like to do is take the APK generated by [MIT AppInventor](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu), open on a Windows Program (writen in C#, the Sample.cs file code) and replace the content of that TXT.

The code i have so far (on the [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OGkqK8ufKRKNpZVxCsISTLo3E4UDYYRJ) folder, file "**Sample.cs**") uses [SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/tree/master/src/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib) to open the APK, find the **Assets\Data.txt** file and replacing it's content; it re-add all the rest.

Also, it changes the Version of the APK (my secondary objective).

The problem is that when i open the APK on my phone it says it's corrupt or it's not a recognized APK. First i thought it was because i changed the Version, so i commented the line that did that, leaving only the TXT change with no better results - still won't work.

Is there something i'm missing here? Anything i could do to not have to recompile/resign the APK? No actual code is changed, and even the Size of the TXT file ends up to be the same.

Comment: It sounds like the APK has some sort of checksum, which you aren't updating correctly.   Why can't you just recompile it?

Comment: wanna do it dynamically; the APK will be available at an intranet site that would put data on the TXT file on the fly.

Comment: rather than modifying the apk file you might want to add some logic into your app and download that cs file from a server depending on your conditions

Comment: the CS file is not the content to change - it's the "program" i made to alter the APK, the changed data is the asset file (TXT). The point would be to download the APK with data set at the download time, contained in the TXT file Asset, the site is in ASPX/C#, so the CS code would be my attempt in making a functionality that would make that alteration. But thanks anyway

Comment: How about you have the asset file dynamically downloaded when you log in to the app ?

Comment: ok - i'll have to do some clarifications later, but one of the data is in fact the url for the site :) It may change and i'd like to provide current URL at download time

Comment: You aren't going to be able to get your app on the app store unless it's signed (and users aren't going to be able to install it unless they disable the right setting, and not many people want or know how to do that).  Why not just create different versions of the app and upload them separately to the app store, then you can just update the app as necessary when the url changes ?

Comment: i'm not publishing it on the app store - this is to run on company phones only, they are downloaded and installed using the APK, and i'd like to put information on it at runtime, on these TXT asset files. One of the cases are updates on the URL, statndard settings and protocols, and custom delivery of employee info on the App - i understand the confusion from my example, but that's the challenge, the answer to the question, "how to change content of an asset text file in a APK without recompile?"

Comment: found this [how-to-modify-an-apk-file](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/05/21/how-to-modify-an-apk-file/) that's basically what i want, but it's Java (and has a Java Sign tool), i'm doing on C#, so i'll study it to see a better way to do it on C#, maybe combined with [RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignData](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.signdata?view=netframework-4.8) method ... still wondering though

Comment: "how to change content of an asset text file in a APK without recompile?" the answer is simple, don't add it as asset, rather download it from a server at runtime... https://puravidaapps.com/filebyfile.php

Comment: no need @Taifun, i'm following that other method from [how-to-modify-an-apk-file](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/05/21/how-to-modify-an-apk-file/), and so far my "zip" code make all the alterations and exclude the 2 files for cert.rsa and cert.sf. I'm verifing on .Net how to generate those 2 files for replacement. If it works i'll place here as a response; as i said to Neil, the goal here is to provide custom information on each download of the APK for each person that downloads it, even if offline.

Comment: So - i left this alone for a while, now i posted a project on github forking from a existing one, but so far i don't yet know if it works (or what would be the right parameters for it: if anyone finds this useful, here it it [SignApk on Github](https://github.com/Sammuel-Miranda/SignApk) )

Comment: left a test apk on the github project, but so far i'm yet to produce a working signed apk (all goes "well", but the phone doesn't intall it - i'm unsure of what i need to sign on the apk content)